# how to change css for a seletor when the selector doesn't exist javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

I have an html file which links to an external css file which has this

```
#bottomBar td {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Now in my javascript, I need something which, if the browser is IE 10, it makes background-color be blue instead of red. Here is what I tried to put in my script

```
if (Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')()) { // this checks if it is IE 10
    $('#bottomBar td').css('background-color', 'blue');
}
```

this doesn't work because it doesn't loop through each bottomBar td since there are none yet. All I want to do is change the actual css regardless of if there is a #bottomBar td or not, I want to be able to change the CSS for it. Any idea how to do this? I want to change the actual text in my css but using

```
$('#bottomBar td').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

doesn't work since the selector

```
$('#bottomBar td')
```

doesn't exist, it doesn't change the background color to red from blue. Note that I have restrictions and cannot use more than one stylesheet and cannot add or remove any additional classes.

Comment: Why are you not using conditional CSS files? Also in your example, you are setting everything to red, not blue.

Comment: @epascarello whoops setting it to red was a typo.. but hm conditional css meaning link to one style sheet if ie 8 and link to another if ie 10? I have some restrictions, I can only use one stylesheet. Is there a way to have different css for different browsers in just one stylesheet?

Comment: @epascarello: I'm not sure what a 'conditional CSS file' is, but if you mean a CSS file loaded from within a conditional comment then it's worth pointing out that IE 10 doesn't support conditional-comment snytax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('body').append('<style>#bottomBar td { background-color: blue; }</style>');`

Comment: This seems like the best way to me, without just including another style sheet if IE 10.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

css:

```
#bottomBar td {
    background-color: red;
}
.ie10 #bottomBar td {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

js:

```
if (Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')()) { // this checks if it is IE 10
    $('body').addClass('ie10');
}
```

Comment: Hm, adding class to the body, this looks like an interesting way to do it. The answer by Ed Cottrell worked so I'm gunna leave it at that (im at the point where I have so much code that if something works, i'm just going to leave it cuz im afraid to change anything since it might stop working) but thanks for this suggestion, I will keep it in mind when I write my next script, it looks liks a good way to do it without a seperate external stylesheet.